# Does shifting unit impulse break evenness?

Tags: signal

My question as we know that unit impulse function is even function as it is symmetric about y-axis but what about when we advance or delay this function is it still remain even function? If not then isn't it contradicts it even property?

Comment: \$\delta(0)\$ is **even**, but *not a function*. We can say it's even, but not that it is an even function. The rest of the question is super easy to answer yourself – take the definition of "even" and apply it. It's not clear how we can help you with this – you haven't shared what you've tried. You also haven't explained why this would disagree with "even property" (it doesn't).

Comment: I also changed your title to actually describe your question, not only the field you're working on!

Comment: Sadly, that is written in a language I don't understand :( Please keep to English, I'd like to be able to follow what you're asking!

Answer (score 3):

<strike>You cannot classify the unit impulse \$\delta(t) \$ as an even or odd function. So the premise of your entire question is false and the question is unanswerable.</strike>

It is possible to show that \$\delta(t)\$ is an **even** function, using the generalized function definition - that is, \$\delta(t)\$ is defined by its effect on other functions rather than its value at every time \$t\$.

The sampling property of \$\delta(t)\$ tells us that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(t) \delta(t) \ \text{d}t = \phi(0).$$

Now consider the same integral, but with a time-inverted impulse function instead

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(t) \delta(-t) \ \text{d}t. $$

Making the variable substitution \$t=-x\$ gives us

$$-\int_{\infty}^{-\infty} \phi(-x) \delta(x) \ \text{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(-x) \delta(x) \ \text{d}x = \phi(0). $$

We have thus shown that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(t) \delta(t) \ \text{d}t = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(t) \delta(-t) \ \text{d}t = \phi(0).$$

This implies that \$\delta(t) = \delta(-t)\$ and shows that an impulse function defined as a generalized function is an **even** function.

The necessity of defining \$\delta(t)\$ as a generalized function comes from the fact that an impulse function is "not easy to deal with". Here is an excerpt from Lathi's *Signal Processing and Linear Systems*:

> The unit impulse function was first defined by P.A.M Dirac as
> $$\delta(t) = 0 \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \: t\neq 0 $$
> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t) \: \text{d}t = 1 \tag{1.21}$$
>
> This definition of the unit impulse function is not mathematically rigourous, which leads to serious difficulties. First, the impulse function does not define a unique function: for example, it can be shown that \$\delta(t) + \dot{\delta(t)}\$ also satisfies (1.21). Moreover, \$\delta(t)\$ is not even a true function in the ordinary sense. An ordinary function is specified by its values for all the time \$t\$. The impulse function is zero everywhere except at \$t=0\$, and at this only interesting part of its range it is undefined.
>
> These difficulties are resolved by defining the impulse as a generalized function rather than an ordinary function. A **generalized function** is defined by its effect on the other functions instead of by its value at every instant of time.

Comment: If you feel like it you can also add the word *abomination*, because that's what a Dirac impulse is. The mathematical representation is charged with correcting that image, for the sake of its extreme usefulness.